# Using ASP Classic to autofit all columns of an Excel Sheet

Tags: excel, vbscript, asp-classic

Hi all I am inserting records into excel using the following format and code

```
sFileName = "abc.xls"

sFilePath = server.mappath("EXCEL\" & sFileName)

Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objCreatedFile = fso.CreateTextFile(sFilePath)
objCreatedFile.close
Set objOpenFile = fso.OpenTextFile(sFilePath,8,True)
    Set rst = server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")    
    sSQL = "select * from a table"
    rst.Open sSQL, conn, 3, 3
    if not rst.eof then
       sStr = "NAME" & chr(9) & "ADDRESS" & char(9) & "TEL" & char(9) 
       objOpenFile.WriteLine sStr

       Do while not rst.eof
          sStr = rst("NAME) & chr(9) & rst("ADD") & char(9) & rst("TEL") & char(9) 
          objOpenFile.WriteLine sStr
       rst.movenext
       loop
    end if
objOpenFile.Close
Set objOpenFile = nothing
Set fso = nothing
```

After inserting the records into excel or rather using excel to open a file with the records separated by tabs. I want to now call something to autofit all the columns in excel. How to do it, please help. Thank you.

Comment: You are creating a tab-delimited text file, not an excel file.  And there's no way (short of some kind of Excel add-in) to have the client's Excel automatically auto-fit the columns when they open the file.

Comment: Thanks Tim, got it. Do you know a better way to write into excel file?

Comment: Look for an ActiveX component that you can create via server.createobject(). Watch out for anything that uses OLE since it relies on Excel being installed on the server and that will not be multi-thread safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tab-delimited text file not an excel file. And there's no way (short of some kind of Excel add-in) to have the client's Excel automatically auto-fit the columns when they open the file